# Postgresql Equivalent of MySQL SHOW CREATE xxx

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Tried to search what are Postgresql equivalent of MySQL's `SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLE-NAME>` and `SHOW CREATE DATABASE <DB-NAME>`. Checking old Answer, it seems impossible. I would have given up if it wasn't for PgAdmin4 which shows them nicely which emboldened me for the search adventure.

So far it have been unsuccessful, with Google showing nothing useful and up-to-date on the issue. trying reading PgAdmin4 proved to be disastrous as I was lost in the code without any guide.

So my question is, is this possible yet? If no how does PgAdmin4 do, if any have an idea?

**Note**: My app is not allowed to modify the database and insert Function at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in SQL, but you can use the `pg_dump` executable to get the complete table definition:

```
pg_dump --schema-only --table=tablename databasename
```

This won't work for databases, however.